# push data in map function

Tags: javascript

I have an object of data

I'm trying to create another array where I have to get every `datapoints` in an array by `rowLabels`.

This is what I expected:

```
[
    [
      {
        value: "250139",
      },
      {
        value: "51798",
      },
      {
        value: "100",
      },
      {
        value: "100",
      },
      {
        value: "100",
      },
      {
        value: "2197",
      },
      {
        value: "483",
      },
      {
        value: "0.88",
      },
      {
        value: "100",
      },
      {
        value: "100",
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        value: "9731",
      },
      {
        value: "2092",
      },
      {
        value: "100",
      },
      {
        value: "3.89",
      },
      {
        value: "100",
      },
      {
        value: "0",
      },
      {
        value: "0",
      },
      {
        value: "0",
      },
      {
        value: "0",
      },
      {
        value: "0",
      },
    ],
  ];
```

**My code:**

```js
let object = {
  "baseId": -1,
  "baseType": "default",
  "rowLabels": [
    "Total",
    "$150+"
  ],
  "groups": [{
      "name": "Total",
      "datapoints": [{
          "uni": "250139",
          "resp": "51798",
          "col": "100",
          "row": "100",
          "idx": "100"
        },
        {
          "uni": "2197",
          "resp": "483",
          "col": "0.88",
          "row": "100",
          "idx": "100"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$50 - $74",
      "datapoints": [{
          "uni": "9731",
          "resp": "2092",
          "col": "100",
          "row": "3.89",
          "idx": "100"
        },
        {
          "uni": "0",
          "resp": "0",
          "col": "0",
          "row": "0",
          "idx": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const DATA = object.rowLabels.map(() => {
  return object.groups.map((nop) => {
    return nop.datapoints.map((val) => {
      return Object.keys(val).map((dat) => {
        switch (dat) {
          case "uni":
            return {
              value: val[dat],
            };
          case "resp":
            return {
              value: val[dat],
            };
          case "col":
            return {
              value: val[dat],
            };
          case "row":
            return {
              value: val[dat],
            };
          case "idx":
            return {
              value: val[dat],
            };
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

console.log(DATA);
```

But the result is different from what I want.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract each object in each `datapoint` property, then map over the value of each property in the object (with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)) and construct a new object.

We can then flatten the resulting array with [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const obj = {
    "baseId": -1,
    "baseType": "default",
    "rowLabels": [
        "Total",
        "$150+"
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "Total",
            "datapoints": [
                {
                    "uni": "250139",
                    "resp": "51798",
                    "col": "100",
                    "row": "100",
                    "idx": "100"
                },
                {
                    "uni": "2197",
                    "resp": "483",
                    "col": "0.88",
                    "row": "100",
                    "idx": "100"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "$50 - $74",
            "datapoints": [
                {
                    "uni": "9731",
                    "resp": "2092",
                    "col": "100",
                    "row": "3.89",
                    "idx": "100"
                },
                {
                    "uni": "0",
                    "resp": "0",
                    "col": "0",
                    "row": "0",
                    "idx": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


const result = obj.groups.map(e => e.datapoints.map(f => Object.values(f).map(g => ({value: g})))).flat()
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Object.keys()` doesn't return the keys in the order you expect. Instead of using Object.keys, use your own, predefined array of keys with your expected order. You can also get rid of the bloated switch/case that way:

```
return ['uni', 'resp', 'col', 'row', 'idx'].map((key) => val[key])
```